# Angular js inherit properties of one controller form another controller

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I m a beginner to angular.. Help me with this code..

How to inherit name property of callme controller to mee controller?
I don know how to use broadcast in this code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callme($scope)
    {
        $scope.name="anand";
    }
    function mee($scope)
    {
        $scope.age="34";
    }
</script>
<div ng-controller="callme">
    <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
    hello {{name}}!
</div>
<div ng-controller="mee">
    <p>age:<input type="text" ng-model="age"></p>
    hello {{name}} {{age}}!!!
</div>
```

Comment: Just put `<div ng-controller="mee">` inside `<div ng-controller="callme">`. Also see guide about [Scope Hierarchies](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#ScopeHierarchies)

Answer (score 1):

So you could use controller inheritance, but that would mean one controller needs to be inside of another controller. That's not what you're doing in your example HTML.

All controllers share 1 rootScope though, so you could go down the road of broadcasting an event from the rootscope, down to all the controllers.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qabpfbug/2/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('callme', [ '$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.name = 'John Doe'; 
    $scope.$watch('name', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('nameChanged', newValue);
    });

}]).controller('mee', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('nameChanged', function(event, value) {
        $scope.name = value;
    });
}]);
```

Let me point out a couple of things:

- The notation of the controllers in this way makes it possible for your code to be minimized ( uglified whatever you want to call it ). The array holds the names of the dependencies which are then injected into the controller function.
- So first we $watch the $scope.name object. AngularJS will check for changing values of this object and call the function in case it changes. In this function we go up to the $rootScope and call a $broadcast with the new value. So this is different from $emit
- On the 'mee' controller - we're listening to the 'nameChanged' event and use the value provided to update the $scope.name object inside that controller.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qabpfbug/1/

You can use $rootScope but instead I suggest you to go use service to share data b/w controllers.

```
 function callme($rootScope)
    {
        $rootScope.name="anand";
    }
    function mee($scope)
    {
        $scope.age="34";
    }
```

Comment: but the value of name is not dynamically added when accessed in "mee" controller..

Comment: you need to $watch on it.